# Comparing String Elements vs Strings

Tags: c++, string

The following code prints

```
1
0
```

And I've been wondering why the values are different if the comparisons are using the same string… I've been struggling with this for a while and cannot figure out why they return different boolean values.

```
int main()
{
    string stringArray[] = { "banana","Banana","zebra","apple","Apple","Zebra","cayote" };

    cout << (stringArray[1] < stringArray[0]) << endl;
    cout << ("Banana" < "banana") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: In the second case you aren't comparing two string objects. The following would work the same as the first case:
`cout << (std::string("Banana") < std::string("banana")) << endl;`

Comment: @ThanePlummer No, this is C++.

Comment: @ThanePlummer: `strncmp` does not work with `std::string`, unless you do the following: `strncmp(stringArray[1].c_str(), stringArray[0].c_str())`.

Comment: @zenith Doesn't matter if it's C or C++, `strcmp` is valid in both languages. @Thomas is correct in pointing out that a conversion is necessary for a `std::string` object.

Comment: While true, in C++ one should (usually) use `std::string` and its comparison operator overloads and the `compare` member function.

Answer (score 17):

`stringArray[n]` is an `std::string`, but `"Banana"` is a string literal (an array of `char`s).

When you do `"Banana" < "banana"`, both string literals are implicitly converted to `char` pointers pointing to the `char` array. `<` then compares those memory addresses.

Answer (score 8):

`"Banana" < "banana"` is not comparing the contents of the strings.  It is comparing the pointers that `"Banana"` and `"banana"` resolve to.

To compare cstyle strings without converting them to a `std::string` you can use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: You could also use `std::string("Banana") < std::string("banana")`

Comment: @Ben: Creating one temporary `std::string` is enough. Although I'd probably do it like this, too, for readability's sake.

Comment: @NathanOliver: For some definition of "a lot"... :) It's certainly less error-prone than using `strcmp` and confusing the three different results. (I must confess I'd have to read the function's documentation to find out if -1 means that the first or the second is greater, or if it can be any negative number, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> string stringArray[] = { "banana","Banana","zebra","apple","Apple","Zebra","cayote" };
> ```

This means that you get a bunch of `std::string` objects, created from `char const*`s resulting from the individual string literals.

Consider a single `std::string` initialisation:

```
std::string s = "...";
```

The literal on the right is of type `char const[4]`. It "decays" to a `char const*` used by `std::string`'s constructor.

The same happens when you initialize an array of `std::string` objects from string literals.

> ```
> cout << (stringArray[1] < stringArray[0]) << endl;
> ```

For `std::string`, using the `<` operator means lexicographical comparison. Therefore, this uses lexicographical comparison and has the expected result.

> ```
> cout << ("Banana" < "banana") << endl;
> ```

In this case, there is no `std::string` involved. You compare two `char const[7]` with each other.

What does this mean? A completely different thing, as it turns out. Both arrays "decay" to a `char const*` to their first element. The result of comparing two unrelated pointers with `<` is **unspecified**. You are lucky to receive 0 as a result, because you may as well receive 1 and not notice the error. Compilers can also generate a warning for this, for example:

```
warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour
```

So, as you can see, this operation has absolutely nothing to do with lexicographical comparison.

One way to solve this problem is to turn at least one of the operands into an `std::string`:

```
cout << (string("Banana") < "banana") << endl;
```

A `<` comparison between an `std::string` and a `char const*` (or vice versa) is defined to be lexicographical.